# Laravel 5.4, одинаковые данные на каждой странице проекта

Tags: laravel, middleware

Суть задачи:
Есть данные (3 выборки из базы), которые должны быть на каждой странице проекта. Т.е. мне нужно их просто "таскать" по каждой странице.

Вопрос:
Как лучше это реализовать, что бы не прописывать в каждом контроллере эти выборки? Предполагаю, что это Middleware, но как сделать не знаю.

Мое решение на данный момент - конструктор с этими выборками, но мне оно не нравится, т.к. при каждом вызове view нужно передавать результаты.

Данные динамичные и выборка должна происходить каждый раз.
Идеальный результат - написать все в одном месте (будь то конструктор, Middleware или что-либо еще) и что бы в каждую view попадали эти значения автоматически.
Ответ с ссылками (не на документацию!) более чем устроит.

P.S. Пишу на QueryBuilder - не хотелось бы использовать eloquent для этого.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто использовать метод [share](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views), добавляете в сервис провайдер свою переменную и она будет отображаться на всех представлениях:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

И теперь используя `$key` вы получите вывод `value` на любом представлении.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень круто и быстро! P.S. словил ошибку  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class 'App\Providers\View' not found - решение в данном коде выше нужно изменить "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;" на "use View;", но это в моем случае - могу быть не прав. В любом случае - огромное спасибо)))))))))

Comment: Всё верно, View используется с глобальной видимости.